# How to get a bibliography from biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I attempt to understand biblatex and try to get Rich Thomason's bibliography, http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~rthomaso/bibs/index.html, to work. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{051916rht.bib}
\begin{document}
Will this be bibliographised? ~\cite{aaker:1981a}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this does not work.

Here are some bib-entries from Thomason's large file:

```
@book{ aaker:1981a,
  author = {David A. Aaker},
  title = {Multivariate Analysis in Marketing},
  edition = {2},
  publisher = {The Scientific Press},
  year = {1981},
  address = {Palo Alto},
  topic = {multivariate-statistics;market-research;}
 }

@incollection{ abb-etal:1996a,
  author = {Bernd Abb and Carsten G\"unther and Michael Herweg and Kai
            Lebeth and Claudia Maienborn and Andrea Schopp},
  title = {Incremental Grammatical Encoding---An Outline of the
        Synphonics Formulator},
  booktitle = {Trends in Natural Language Generation, An Artificial
        Intelligence Perspective, Fourth {E}uropean Workshop,
        {EWNLG} '93, Pisa, Italy, April 28-30, 1993, Selected
        Papers},
  publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
  series = {Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
  volume = {1036},
  year = {1996},
  editor = {Giovanni Adorni and Michael Zock},
  pages = {277--299},
  address = {New York},
  topic = {nl-generation;nl-realization;}
  }

@inproceedings{ abbate-thiel_u:2003a,
  author = {Marcello L'Abbate and Ulrich Thiel},
  title = {The Use of Contextual Information in a Proactivity Model
        for Conversational Agents},
  booktitle = {Modeling and Using Context: Fourth International and
    Interdisciplinary Conference, Context 2003},
  publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
  year = {2003},
  editor = {Patrick Blackburn and Chiara Ghidini and Roy M. Turner
    and Fausto Giunchiglia},
  pages = {459--466},
  address = {Berlin},
  topic = {context;HCI;}
  }

@unpublished{ abbott_b:1974a,
  author = {Barbara Abbott},
  title = {Some Problems in Giving an Adequate Model-Theoretical
    Account of {CAUSE}},
  year = {1974},
  rtnote = {In RHT collection.  Judging from a note attached, it may
    have been published in BLS 3, 1975.  Check this out.},
  note = {Unpublished manuscript.},
  topic = {causality;}
  }

@unpublished{ abbott_b:1974b,
  author = {Barbara Abbott},
  title = {Some Remarks Concerning {H}intikka's Theory of Propositional
    Attitudes},
  year = {1974},
  rtnote = {In RHT collection.},
  note = {Unpublished manuscript.},
  topic = {propositional-attitudes;}
  }

@unpublished{ abbott_b:1975a,
  author = {Barbara Abbott},
  title = {Remarks on `Belief-Contexts'\,},
  year = {1975},
  rtnote = {In RHT collection.},
  note = {Unpublished manuscript.},
  topic = {propositional-attitudes;}
  }

@phdthesis{ abbott_b:1976a,
  author = {Barbara Abbott},
  title = {A Study of Referential Opacity},
  school = {Linguistics Department, University of California at Berkeley},
  year = {1976},
  type = {Ph.{D}. Dissertation},
  address = {Berkeley, California},
  rtnote = {In RHT collection.  LLP authored shelves.},
  missinginfo = {Date is a guess},
  topic = {intensionality;}
 }
```

I believe the errors occur because Thomason's bibliography is not always compatible with biblatex. If so, this is unfortunate because Thomason's bibliography is very useful.

Comment: I believe there must be some incompatibility btw Thomason's bibliography and biblatex. It is very unfortunate if this is the case.

Comment: I opened the blg-file, and the message is informative, I believe: [7648] Utils.pm:149> WARN - Entry aczel:1994a does not parse correctly
[8673] Utils.pm:149> WARN - Entry allen_jf-etal:1991b does not parse correctly
[8688] Utils.pm:165> ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: /var/folders/5g/8wvj04b14pq7lc0gyyfjx2xm0000gn/T/W8cm802UOH/051916rht.bib_6358.utf8, line 1326, syntax error: found ";", expected end of entry ("}" or ")") (skipping to next "@")

Comment: If you could isolate the error, please post an answer explaining what the error was and how to resolve it. That way others may benefit from it. You may also want to contact the author of the `.bib` file to inform them of the issue. That said, the quoted entries don't look like they are optimised for `biblatex` and don't always seem to follow what I would consider best practice.

Comment: @moewe I mentioned what I believe the problem is. Rewriting the bibliography to fit biblatex is a large task and R. Thomason is retired. Perhaps Philpapers may be interested in the topic. It would have been nice if there were a Wikibook-style introduction to biblatex.

Comment: @moewe The file has lots of errors in it, of various sorts. And I agree that it uses various bad habits, especially in name formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, following your [given link](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~rthomaso/bibs/index.html) one get the following screen:

[image: resulting web page]

For me it is very clear that this bibliography is/was build for `bibtex` and **not** for `biblatex` and/or `biber`.

Now it seems that this 8 MB (sic!) great bibliography contains error as you can see in your cited error message in your comment:

> syntax error: found ";", expected end of entry ("}" or ")") (skipping
>   to next "@")

In `bibtex` syntax you need to end an entry field with an `,` and not with an `;`, that means that is clearly a bug in that file (can you please add the related bib entry to your question, too -- I do not want to download such 8MB file ...)

Then let us have a look to one `bib` entry:

```
@unpublished{abbott_b:1974a,
  author = {Barbara Abbott},
  title  = {Some Problems in Giving an Adequate Model-Theoretical
            Account of {CAUSE}},
  year   = {1974},
  rtnote = {In RHT collection.  Judging from a note attached, it may
            have been published in BLS 3, 1975.  Check this out.},
  note   = {Unpublished manuscript.},
  topic  = {causality;}
}
```

The fields `rtnote` and `topic` are not standard fields for `bibtex` as far as I know. (Or there is a special bibliographystyle handling this fields I did not find mentioned on the web page.)

To be able to find all errors in that bib file you should first test the file with `\nocite{*}` and `bibtex` ... (There is an answer of mine how to do that, but at the moment I can not find it :-( )

If you want to use the advantages of `biblatex`/`biber` you have to change some field names and values in this `bibtex` file. Please have a closer look to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/16550) and its answers to learn what have to be changed. You also have to think about the fields `rtnote` and `topic` how to rename them, perhaps `keywords` for `topic` or to create a special handling for this fields with `biblatex` ...

However, that means you have to rework each bib entry in the original bib file to make it best usable with `biblatex`/`biber`. That -- indeed -- will be a lot of work ...

Or, if you need only some bib entries of this file, copy them into a new bib file and prepare it for the usage of `biblatex`/`biber` as mentioned above ...

**Conclusion:**

The linked bib file seems to contain errors which has to be corrected and was made for the usage with `bibtex`. It has to be changed to use the advantages `biblatex`/`biber` offered you ...

**Conclusion 2:**

To start learning `biblatex`/`biber` better take a short bib file from one of your old projects and play with it to change it to get the advantages of `biblatex`/`biber` ...

**BTW:**

With the following mwe (your given bib entrys and a little bit changed code to get all entries printed, copy it and name it `mwe.tex` in a new directory for testing):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{aaker:1981a,
  author    = {David A. Aaker},
  title     = {Multivariate Analysis in Marketing},
  edition   = {2},
  publisher = {The Scientific Press},
  year      = {1981},
  address   = {Palo Alto},
  topic     = {multivariate-statistics;market-research;}
}

@incollection{abb-etal:1996a,
  author = {Bernd Abb and Carsten G\"unther and Michael Herweg and Kai
            Lebeth and Claudia Maienborn and Andrea Schopp},
  title = {Incremental Grammatical Encoding---An Outline of the
        Synphonics Formulator},
  booktitle = {Trends in Natural Language Generation, An Artificial
        Intelligence Perspective, Fourth {E}uropean Workshop,
        {EWNLG} '93, Pisa, Italy, April 28-30, 1993, Selected
        Papers},
  publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
  series = {Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
  volume = {1036},
  year = {1996},
  editor = {Giovanni Adorni and Michael Zock},
  pages = {277--299},
  address = {New York},
  topic = {nl-generation;nl-realization;}
  }

@inproceedings{abbate-thiel_u:2003a,
  author = {Marcello L'Abbate and Ulrich Thiel},
  title = {The Use of Contextual Information in a Proactivity Model
        for Conversational Agents},
  booktitle = {Modeling and Using Context: Fourth International and
    Interdisciplinary Conference, Context 2003},
  publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
  year = {2003},
  editor = {Patrick Blackburn and Chiara Ghidini and Roy M. Turner
    and Fausto Giunchiglia},
  pages = {459--466},
  address = {Berlin},
  topic = {context;HCI;}
  }

@unpublished{abbott_b:1974a,
  author = {Barbara Abbott},
  title = {Some Problems in Giving an Adequate Model-Theoretical
    Account of {CAUSE}},
  year = {1974},
  rtnote = {In RHT collection.  Judging from a note attached, it may
    have been published in BLS 3, 1975.  Check this out.},
  note = {Unpublished manuscript.},
  topic = {causality;}
  }

@unpublished{abbott_b:1974b,
  author = {Barbara Abbott},
  title = {Some Remarks Concerning {H}intikka's Theory of Propositional
    Attitudes},
  year = {1974},
  rtnote = {In RHT collection.},
  note = {Unpublished manuscript.},
  topic = {propositional-attitudes;}
  }

@unpublished{abbott_b:1975a,
  author = {Barbara Abbott},
  title = {Remarks on `Belief-Contexts'\,},
  year = {1975},
  rtnote = {In RHT collection.},
  note = {Unpublished manuscript.},
  topic = {propositional-attitudes;}
  }

@phdthesis{abbott_b:1976a,
  author = {Barbara Abbott},
  title = {A Study of Referential Opacity},
  school = {Linguistics Department, University of California at Berkeley},
  year = {1976},
  type = {Ph.{D}. Dissertation},
  address = {Berkeley, California},
  rtnote = {In RHT collection.  LLP authored shelves.},
  missinginfo = {Date is a guess},
  topic = {intensionality;}
 }
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Will this be bibliographised?~\cite{aaker:1981a}. 
\nocite{*} % <=========================== to get all bib entries printed

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

you get following result (see, that fields `rtnote` and `topic` are **not** handled!):

[image: resulting bibliography]

compiled with no error message and one warning (resulting from the usage of package `filecontents`) ...

Comment: I think this overstates the problem of using standard `bibtex` `.bib` files with `biblatex`. Most of us who use `biblatex` have large `.bib` files like this that we have accumulated over the years when we used `natbib`, and they generally pose no problems for `biblatex` either. The main problem with this `.bib` file is that it has a number of errors in the entries. Once those errors are corrected, the file should work fine. Both `bibtex` and `biber` ignore fields they don't know about.